# Eigenvalues computation using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'm computing the eigenvalues of a matrix using sympy last version 1.12:

```
from sympy import Matrix
M = Matrix( [[0, 1.0, 0, 1.0], [1.0, 0, -0.50, 0], [0, 1.0, 0, -1.0], [-0.50, 0, 1.0, 0]])
M.eigenvals()
```

Given that M is real, the eigenvalues should appear in conjugate pairs, but I obtain this output:

```
{3.49869741491636e-64 - 1.35013912450988*I: 1, -0.907124939317785 + 3.82549612092643e-64*I: 1, 0.907124939317785 + 9.90959643144198e-65*I: 1, 1.35013912450988*I: 1}
```

Is this a precision problem or is there something I am not considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues are in complex conjugate pairs except that there are small floating point errors:

```
3.49869741491636e-64 - 1.35013912450988*I
-0.907124939317785 + 3.82549612092643e-64*I
0.907124939317785 + 9.90959643144198e-65*I
1.35013912450988*I
```

You should consider the tiny numbers with `e-64` as being basically just zero which means that the eigenvalues here are actually:

```
-1.35013912450988*I
-0.907124939317785
0.907124939317785
1.35013912450988*I
```

So the 2nd and 3rd values here are real and the 1st and 4th are an imaginary complex conjugate pair.

The reason that the calculation is approximate is because you are using a matrix of floats. If instead you use exact rational numbers then you can get an exact representation of the eigenvalues:

```
In [6]: M
Out[6]: 
⎡ 0    1.0   0    1.0 ⎤
⎢                     ⎥
⎢1.0    0   -0.5   0  ⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎢ 0    1.0   0    -1.0⎥
⎢                     ⎥
⎣-0.5   0   1.0    0  ⎦

In [7]: M.applyfunc(nsimplify)
Out[7]: 
⎡ 0    1   0    1 ⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎢ 1    0  -1/2  0 ⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎢ 0    1   0    -1⎥
⎢                 ⎥
⎣-1/2  0   1    0 ⎦

In [8]: M.applyfunc(nsimplify).eigenvals()
Out[8]: 
⎧       ________           ________          __________         __________   ⎫
⎪      ╱ 1   √7           ╱ 1   √7          ╱   1   √7         ╱   1   √7    ⎪
⎨-ⅈ⋅  ╱  ─ + ── : 1, ⅈ⋅  ╱  ─ + ── : 1, -  ╱  - ─ + ── : 1,   ╱  - ─ + ── : 1⎬
⎪   ╲╱   2   2         ╲╱   2   2        ╲╱     2   2       ╲╱     2   2     ⎪
⎩                                                                            ⎭
```

If you compute the eigenvalues exactly then you can evaluate them numerically without the small rounding errors:

```
In [15]: [r.n() for r in M.applyfunc(nsimplify).eigenvals()]
Out[15]: [-1.35013912450988⋅ⅈ, 1.35013912450988⋅ⅈ, -0.907124939317785, 0.907124939317785]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not so familiar with linear algebra but when i calculate the eigenvalues with numpy, then the eigenvalues eigenvalues should appear in conjugate pairs

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
 
c = np.array([[0, 1.0, 0, 1.0], [1.0, 0, -0.50, 0], [0, 1.0, 0, -1.0], [-0.50, 0, 1.0, 0]])

d = np.linalg.eig(c)
```

This is the output:

```
(array([-9.07124939e-01+0.j        , -6.07439883e-16+1.35013912j,
       -6.07439883e-16-1.35013912j,  9.07124939e-01+0.j        ]), 

array([[ 7.07106781e-01+0.00000000e+00j, -1.52205044e-01-2.07839335e-16j,
            -1.52205044e-01+2.07839335e-16j,  7.07106781e-01+0.00000000e+00j],
           [-5.27820584e-01+0.00000000e+00j, -3.64694221e-16+3.74597273e-01j,
            -3.64694221e-16-3.74597273e-01j,  5.27820584e-01+0.00000000e+00j],
           [ 4.56615131e-01+0.00000000e+00j,  7.07106781e-01+0.00000000e+00j,
             7.07106781e-01-0.00000000e+00j,  4.56615131e-01+0.00000000e+00j],
           [-1.13613611e-01+0.00000000e+00j,  1.67972808e-16-5.80095257e-01j,
             1.67972808e-16+5.80095257e-01j,  1.13613611e-01+0.00000000e+00j]]))
```

The first array delivers the eigenvalues. The second array shows the eigenvectors.